# Exo Player Is it possible to dynamically play ranges of an mp3 file without clipping?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm new to the audio world so sorry if I'm not using the right terminology.

I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically play ranges of an mp3 file. So when I need it to I could specify a range and have only that range play from the mp3. I thought that the clipping function Exo Player has might work but I don't want to have to release the source and recreate it every time I want to move the range in the file.

In my research I kept coming across this enhancement request: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3163
I've looked over the release notes for Exo Player but haven't seen anything like that since the mentioned release. Is what I'm trying achieve possible? If so how would I implement something like that? It seems like I'm missing something really simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I came across this: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2828

The suggested pattern is to use a `Handler` and `Runnable` to achieve what I'm after.

After some fiddling here is what I got working:

```java
import android.os.Handler

fun play() {
  if (!player.isPlayer) {
    player.seekTo(0)
    player.playWhenReady = true
    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable { 
      pause()
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

I initially ran into some strange problems with the handler because it had imported a different library.